# Representing UNO out parameters in definitions

Tags: typescript, libreoffice, uno

The UNO API supports `inout` and `out` parameters -- a variable is passed into a function, the function modifies the variable, and the modified variable is then available outside the function.

Javascript doesn't support this type of parameter call, so the Automation bridge [enables a workaround](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Return_Values) -- passing in an array; the element at index `0` is modified, and can be retrieved outside the function:

```
// for inout parameters
let inout = ['input value'];
obj.func(inout);
console.log(inout[0]); //could print 'new value'
```

For `inout` parameters, since an initial value is expected, the function could be declared with a tuple type:

```
declare interface Obj {
    func(inout: [string]): void;
}
```

However, an `out` parameter doesn't need an initial value:

```
// Javascript

let out = [];
obj.func1(out);
console.log(out[0]); // could print 'new value'
```

AFAIK there is no way to represent the empty tuple type, and an empty array is incompatible with the tuple type. If I declare the function argument with a tuple type, I cannot pass in an empty array:

```
// Typescript

declare interface Obj {
    func1(out: [string]): void;
}
let out = [];
obj.func1(out); 
// Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string]'.
//  Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]'.
```

[link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20interface%20Obj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20func1(out%3A%20%5Bstring%5D)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20out%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20Obj%3B%0D%0Aobj.func1(out)%3B%0D%0A)

There are two hacks I could use:

1. either subvert the type system using `any`:

   ```
   let out: [string] = [] as any;
   ```
2. or use an initialized array:

   ```
   let out: [string] = [''];
   ```

**Is there any less "hacky" way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `inout` parameter as `inout: string[]`, which enables you  to pass on an empty array.

e.g.:

```
declare interface Obj {
    func(inout: string[]): void;
};

const Obj: Obj = {
    func(inout: string[]) {
        // ...
    }
}

let arr = [];
Obj.func(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Until TypeScript allows empty tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13126), you could consider declaring the parameter type as `undefined[]`.

Comment: Wouldn't using `undefined[]` cause all type information about the individual members to be lost?

Comment: Also, even once empty tuples are allowed, I'd have to explicitly cast it after the call to the non-empty tuple type.